# Given a type, how to find all functiion I need to implement

Tags: types, julia

I am reading Christopher Rackauckas's excellent Julia blog [Type-Dispatch Design: Post Object-Oriented Programming for Julia](http://www.stochasticlifestyle.com/type-dispatch-design-post-object-oriented-programming-julia/)

In it he describes how "in an object-oriented programming language you group by implementation details, in typed-dispatch programming you group by actions".  For example, in the blog there is a code example with AbstractPerson, which is described as "a Person is someone who has a name which can be gotten by get_name".

So, if I am using some library which uses some type, and I want to make my own implementation of that type, how can I list all the functions I need to implement?  For example, if I wish to make my own Person type, how do I discover that one needs to correctly handle a get_name function?

Does Julia keep track of this information, and if so, how do I access it?

Comment: Did my edit to the title get it right? Seems like title and body didn't match

Comment: Great!  Thank you

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is typically called an [*interface*](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/interfaces/). Currently, interfaces  are only informal in Julia. They are usually specified in the documentation of a package or Julia itself. For example, see [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/interfaces/#man-interface-array-1) the interface definition for `AbstractArray`. Hence there is no built in function that lists all the mandatory methods that you must implement. However, interfaces might become first class in future Julia versions.

To answer your title question, you might want to take a look at [`methodswith(type)`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/InteractiveUtils/#InteractiveUtils.methodswith). Note, though, that this won't give you *all* methods that can be called with an object of the given `type` (take a look at the optional keyword argument `supertypes::Bool`.

Comment: One can also write tests suit functions  for it the implentor call. FilePathsBase does this

Comment: Thank you, that's perfect!  Julia rocks :-D